# Design and Equipment Advice

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm looking to change my home network.

I have a cable internet provider and a wireless router. This router is in the living room. The wireless signal is poor on the back of the house.

What I'm thinking of doing is the following:

Direct to the cable modem connect an atom computer with 2 ethernet cards, and put linux on it, to serve as the router/dhcp server/firewall...

From this linux router connect a switch, with will connect all the wired stuff (printer, NAS, PC), and from the switch connect 2 access points, one in the living and one at the back of the house.

Can you guys comment on this design? Does you think of a better solution?

For a home design, can you give me some switches (gigabit, min 5 ports) and access points (Wireless N or AC) advices... That will do these work and dont cost much...

Thanks

Comment: This post is very opinion based, and although it's well worded and clear, I think it's off topic here I'm afraid. http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask It also seems like you want us to recommend hardware, which is also off topic http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Run Ethernet over your electrical wiring? I never actually used it before but the technology is out there, Google or Wiki Power-line communication.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good setup. Instead of using an atom pc as router, there also exist embedded hardware boards which are more efficient in terms of performance and energy, like the `Soekris` boards which can be used together with for example `m0n0wall` and `pfSense`.

Comment: Does you know some access points that will fit this design?